# Check if a Char represents a non-character codepoint in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In C++ Qt framework, Qchar type has method named [isNonCharacter()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html#isNonCharacter) which Returns true if the QChar is a non-character. Is there any similar method for Kotlin Char type.

Comment: @m0skit0 Unicode has a certain number of code points that are classified as "non-characters:" that is, they can be used for internal purposes in applications but cannot be used for text interchange. Those are the last two entries each Unicode Plane ([0xfffe..0xffff], [0x1fffe..0x1ffff], etc.) as well as the entries in range [0xfdd0..0xfdef].

Comment: Worst naming ever.

Comment: See http://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#noncharacters

Comment: Since the ranges are fixed and known, I'd consider just writing it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin provides a [Char.isDefined()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-defined.html) extension method that seems to do just what you want (or at least, the direct opposite).

So you can do e.g.:

```
val c = 10000.toChar()
if (!c.isDefined())
    throw Exception("Char is not defined")
```

(This function is available in Kotlin/JVM and Kotlin/Native, but not in Kotlin/JS yet.)

Comment: Could you please tell an example of not defined character.

Comment: @Vencat The first few examples are U+0378, U+0379, U+0380 to U+0383, U+038B…  There are 1676 in the BMP (0–65535).

Comment: Based on those examples and the linked Qt docs, these seem like different concepts.  "[Non-characters] are the last two entries each Unicode Plane ([0xfffe..0xffff], [0x1fffe..0x1ffff], etc.) as well as the entries in range [0xfdd0..0xfdef]."